# Want to show Google Analytics API on my client websites with very basic report saving in PHP via cron job

Tags: php, google-analytics, cron

Currently I am in need to show the reporting of my client websites. All of the websites have the GA code installed on the.
I want to show the Basic Report of the visitors based on the Google Analytics (GA code) on each of the websites.

I looked at many threads and php classes as well, and stopped at 2 links 
1. https://code.google.com/p/gapi-google-analytics-php-interface/
2. [PHP Google Analytics API - Simple example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21024672/php-google-analytics-api-simple-example)

But the first one is outdated and second one requires Authorization 2.0 etc.

Can anyone tell me is there any class or some method by which I can easily access the basic reports from Google Analytics on daily basis (Total Visitors, Unique Visitors, Old Visitors, New Visitors, Source of Visitors)?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, I was thinking something that can happen with PHP Scripts only :) No emails etc.

Comment: it'd save you hassle if you can't figure it out in the interim

Answer (score 0):

There is a useful script [php-ga](http://code.google.com/p/php-ga/) by thomas bachem on github. I'm sure you could configure it to run daily.

Sample (basic) code:

```
use UnitedPrototype\GoogleAnalytics;

// Initilize GA Tracker
$tracker = new GoogleAnalytics\Tracker('UA-12345678-9', 'example.com');

// Assemble Visitor information
// (could also get unserialized from database)
$visitor = new GoogleAnalytics\Visitor();
$visitor->setIpAddress($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
$visitor->setUserAgent($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
$visitor->setScreenResolution('1024x768');

// Assemble Session information
// (could also get unserialized from PHP session)
$session = new GoogleAnalytics\Session();

// Assemble Page information
$page = new GoogleAnalytics\Page('/page.html');
$page->setTitle('My Page');

// Track page view
$tracker->trackPageview($page, $session, $visitor);
```